# Execution of a QueryTask for ArcGISDynamicMapService

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am going to display the query results on infotemplate. I have written the code which I have mentioned below. After execution of this code just getting a point on map but not getting infowindow popup. Please suggest me where I have to modify my code to the query results on infotemplate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/"></script>
<script>
  var map;
  require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer", "esri/layers/ImageParameters", "esri/tasks/QueryTask", "esri/tasks/query", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dojo/_base/Color", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, ImageParameters, QueryTask, Query, SimpleMarkerSymbol, InfoTemplate, Color) {
    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "topo",  //For full list of pre-defined basemaps, navigate to http://arcg.is/1JVo6Wd
      center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
      zoom: 5
    }); 
    var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer", {
      "opacity" : 0.5,        
      "infoTemplate" : infoTemplate
      });
      map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer);
      //map.on("click",executeQueryTask);
      dojo.connect(map, "onClick", executeQueryTask);

    var queryTask = new QueryTask("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3");        

    var query = new Query();
     query.returnGeometry = true;
     query.outFields = ["STATE_NAME", "SUB_REGION", "POP2000"];
     //query.where = "STATE_NAME = 'WYOMING'";
    var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${STATE_NAME}", "Sub Region : ${SUB_REGION}<br/> Population : ${POP2000}");

    var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
    symbol.setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE);
    symbol.setSize(10);
    symbol.setColor(new Color([255,255,0,0.5]));

    function executeQueryTask(evt) {
        query.geometry = evt.mapPoint;  
        queryTask.execute(query,showResults);
    }
    function showResults(featureSet) {  
        map.graphics.clear();
  //Performance enhancer - assign featureSet array to a single variable.
  var resultFeatures = featureSet.features;
  //Loop through each feature returned
  for (var i=0, il=resultFeatures.length; i<il; i++) {
    //Get the current feature from the featureSet.
    //Feature is a graphic
    var graphic = resultFeatures[i];
    graphic.setSymbol(symbol);

    //Set the infoTemplate.
    graphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);

    //Add graphic to the map graphics layer.
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
        }
    }       
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which API version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  var map,mapPoint;

    require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer", "esri/layers/ImageParameters", "esri/tasks/QueryTask", "esri/tasks/query", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dojo/_base/Color", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, ImageParameters, QueryTask, Query, SimpleMarkerSymbol, InfoTemplate, Color) {
map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "topo",  //For full list of pre-defined basemaps, navigate to http://arcg.is/1JVo6Wd
  center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
  zoom: 5
});

//var imageParameters = new ImageParameters();
//imageParameters.format = "jpeg";

var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer", {
  "opacity" : 0.5,        
  "infoTemplate" : infoTemplate
  });
  map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer);

  //map.on("click",executeQueryTask);
  dojo.connect(map, "onClick", executeQueryTask);

var queryTask = new QueryTask("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3");        

var query = new Query();
 query.returnGeometry = true;
 query.outFields = ["STATE_NAME", "SUB_REGION", "POP2000"];
 //query.where = "STATE_NAME = 'WYOMING'";
var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${STATE_NAME}", "Sub Region : ${SUB_REGION}<br/> Population : ${POP2000}");

var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
symbol.setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE);
symbol.setSize(10);
symbol.setColor(new Color([255,255,0,0.5]));

function executeQueryTask(evt) {
    mapPoint =evt.mapPoint;
    query.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
    //var params = {"Input_File":dataFile}

    queryTask.execute(query,showResults);
}
function showResults(featureSet) {

    map.graphics.clear();

    var resultFeatures = featureSet.features;

    for (var i=0, il=resultFeatures.length; i<il; i++) {
//Get the current feature from the featureSet.
//Feature is a graphic

var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${STATE_NAME}", "Sub Region : ${SUB_REGION}<br/> Population : ${POP2000}");

  resultFeatures[i].setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
    }
     map.infoWindow.setFeatures(resultFeatures);
     map.infoWindow.show(mapPoint);

}

});
```

Comment: Hi emredelioglu, thanks for giving the suggession, but after modifying my code with your suggession, a new issue is raising. i.e. the infotemplate is not changing its query fields while clicking outside of our featurelayer.

Comment: add `map.graphics.clear()`  after line `map.infoWindow.clearFeatures();` if dont like it , change `map.infoWindow.setFeatures(resultFeatures);
     map.infoWindow.show(mapPoint);`to `if (resultFeatures.length>0){
     map.infoWindow.setFeatures(resultFeatures);
     map.infoWindow.show(mapPoint);
    } else{
      map.infoWindow.hide();
    }`

Comment: Thank, and i want to display all fields on my infoeindow, please suggest how can I get.

Comment: change `new InfoTemplate("${STATE_NAME}", "Sub Region : ${SUB_REGION}<br/> Population : ${POP2000}");`  to `new InfoTemplate("${*}");`

Comment: Thanks for your suggission, and I want to display another query results from var queryTask1 = new QueryTask("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/2"); layer for all fields in the same infowindow. Please suggest me how to do it.

Comment: [Arcgis JS Sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/query_deferred_list.html) check this link